# How to Surround-with ... in Visual Studio Editor like Sublime Text?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, editor, code-editor

In Sublime Text the default behaviour is to surround selected text with hyphens or brackets depending on what I pressed. Is there an option or configuration similar to that behaviour in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how to surround-with in Visual Studio, you can check out [this page on the Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hf704tz.aspx):

> **To use surround-with code snippets through keyboard shortcut**
>
> 1. In the Visual Studio IDE, open the file that you intend to edit.
> 2. In the Code
>    Editor, select text to surround.
> 3. Type CTRL+K, CTRL+S.
> 4. Select the code snippet from the code snippet list using the mouse, or by typing the name of the code snippet and pressing TAB or ENTER.